# How to correctly divide API tests into test cases

Tags: python, pytest

I'm practicing API testing and I'm wondering what the correct approach to dividing tests into test cases is. For example, `GET` gives me a JSON which is a list of items and I want to check a few things in one of the values for each item in the list - make sure it's not null, that it is a float and that the value is greater than 10. This is what I've come up with:

```
def test_demo():
    response = requests.get(url)
    for item in response.json():
        val = item["score"]
        assert val is not None
        assert type(val) is float
        assert val > 10.0
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I'm mainly wondering if a `for` loop is the correct way of checking every item in a list and if it's good practice to have 3 assertions in one test or if I should divide each one of them into a different test.

Also, if every test uses the same API endpoint, is it a good idea to store it in a variable at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Have you looked into using the pydantic package?  It’s great for data validation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told to respect a structure "given-when-then" when doing unit testing.

Meaning, "given A when doing B then should be C". So I would split the assertion in different tests. I really try to have one assertion per test.

For your second question, yes if it use the same endpoint I would store it in a variable.